# Store information inside the executable

Tags: linux, windows

I really don't like that programs store their information all over the filesystem - in /etc, sometimes /var, /tmp, in a hidden folder in a user's home directory...

I want to find a way to store information inside the executable itself. The end effect would be that there is zero litter left behind by the program. To completely remove it, you would just remove the executable and be done (if it's statically compiled). If you would move the executable to another computer, all settings would be preserved.

I think the best fit for this task is C++, or at least C. Since you can make compiler bombs with those, you can arbitrarily define an executable's size. Then, at runtime, you could manually alter the bytes in the executable and later read those bytes, e.g. when loading user settings.

A problem I can foresee is the filesystem refusing to alter the executable at runtime, since it's in use by a process.

If anyone has any thoughts to share, I would like to hear them.

Comment: You'll also trip all the codesigning, antivirus, antimalware stuff on the planet. If you're writing the software, just don't litter the computer all over. Store all the settings in a single file. And make the location of said file configurable.

Comment: @Mat my line of thinking was to, perhaps, someday push this as a standard to prevent *other* apps from cluttering PCs.